# Python: Write high volume of data (200K+ recs) to an existing excel (xlsx) file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlsx

I have a requirement of writing 200K+ records into an **existing excel file** (xlsx). The excel file has some designated header rows and I need to write after that. Sometimes I may have to append rows to an existing excel file which already have some data rows.

Data exist in a local sqlite database, I run a sql query on that to fetch the data (I'm using dense rank and over partition functionality in SQL for easy processing).

Currently, I'm using **openpyxl**. I loop through each row from the sql cursor and write data to each cell in excel. I'm saving the workbook after every 3000 rows are written so that I do not get memory issue. Its running fine but taking around **5+ hours**. I have tried **win32com** and its taking even more time.

How can I improve the performance of this data writing process?

My current sample code is given below.

```
    al_row = al_headerRow
    
    for sql_row in cursor.execute(ALSheet_SQL_Select):
        al_row = al_row + 1
        al_col = 0

        #Loop thru all the fields in the sheet
        #Seq in AL Sheet and Mapping sheet should match
        for al_field in dictMappingDoc[ALSheet]:
            al_col = al_col + 1
            #SQL Cursor output will be retrieved like a list, first element index is 0, hence excel col 1 will be SQL list index 0.
            al_col_sql = al_col - 1
            
            ws.cell(row=al_row,column=al_col).value = sql_row[al_col_sql]
        #End - for - al_field in dictMappingDoc[ALSheet]

        #Interim save to clear memory
        save_counter = save_counter + 1
        if save_counter == 3000:
            wb.save(filename = TempFilePath)
            sleep(5)
            save_counter = 0
        #End - if
    #End - for - SQL Row
    
#---- Final Save -----
wb.save(filename = TempFilePath)
sleep(10)
wb.close()
```

Comment: Have you consider do this using C++ ? Here a library  https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX that could help you.

Comment: Hey thanks. I need to use python. Because its a part of the application I'm building.

Comment: You could try to create the file using the underlying XML format (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181.aspx for specs).  Performance should be much faster at the expense of not using a library with error checking, and having to update the output yourself based on spec changes (very rare).

Comment: You can also think of pandas to write to excel file. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Thank you @VenkataramanR but with ExcelWriter function, I get pylint error. Abstract class 'ExcelWriter' with abstract methods instantiated pylint(abstract-class-instantiated)

Comment: @yk11 as I'm writing to an existing file, do you know how can I decompress the xlsx file?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Venkataraman R ,use pandas. I am working with more than 1,3m records excel file and it takes only a few seconds to parse.

1/ [read](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) your existing excel file to a dataframe

2/Use your sql cursor loop to update the dataframe using either loc, iloc or whatever fits you :`df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value_you got_from_sql]`Whenever you need to add a new row, just add it to a temporary dataframe that you will [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) at the end

3/ [write](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) your excel file

Comment: Thank you @Myrt . I can directly assign the sql output as dataframe, example `df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.execute(ALSheet_SQL_Select))`, its writing as per the layout requirement, but its creating a new file and writing it. To write to an existing file, I have to initialize the ExcelWriter. For ExcelWriter, I'm getting this error "Abstract class 'ExcelWriter' with abstract methods instantiated pylint(abstract-class-instantiated)". Any suggestion on how to overcome this?

Comment: PS: The existing excel is a template which will be used as an input for another application. It has certain color coding, hidden values in the header rows which I shouldn't alter. I should just append to same file after the header row.